# SQL export results in blank file name if I add timestamp

Tags: phpmyadmin

I am using phpMyAdmin 4.5.5.1, PHP 5.6.18 and Apache 2.4.18. I am trying to include a timestamp in my SQL export file name but when I add the parameters (`@database@_%Y%m%d%H%i%s`) I get a blank file name. It just saves it as `.sql`. If I exclude the timestamp paramters (just `@database@`) then it includes the database name, i.e. `my_database.sql`.

What am I doing wrong!?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Turns out, the parameters have changed; see [strftime](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strftime.php). `%i` (minutes) is now `%M` and `%s` (seconds) is now `%S`. To get a full timestamp, you would need something like `@DATABASE@_%Y%m%d%H%M%S`.

Comment: You can also use `@database@-%F-%T` for e.g. `mydb-2017-08-16-10_37_00` . source: https://duntuk.com/phpmyadmin-database-export-save-file-template